# wmic find information and place them in another txt file

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename, wmic

I'm working on a code to search information. I use wmic for it.

1. I ask with WMIC the 'installed programs' and export them to tmp.txt
2. I want to filter tmp.txt and place the results in another text document.

But there is something wrong. I don't get the results for the computers in a txt file.

This is the code I created:

```
@echo off
title Check software
color 1f

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set YYYY=%dt:~0,4%
set MM=%dt:~4,2%
set DD=%dt:~6,2%
set HH=%dt:~8,2%
set Min=%dt:~10,2%
set Sec=%dt:~12,2%
set timestamp=Datum-%YYYY%%MM%%DD%--Tijd-%HH%%Min%%Sec%

set txt=results--%timestamp%.txt

if exist "1e-client" (
        echo Check: Map aanwezig
        goto :checkfolder
    ) else (
        echo Check: Map NIET aanwezig
        echo Map 1e-client maken...
        mkdir "1e-client"
        goto :checkfolder
    )

:checkfolder
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%I in (list.txt) do call :pinger %%I goto :eof

:eof
move %txt% 1e-client
exit

:pinger

ping -4 -n 1 -w 1000 %1
if not errorlevel 1 set pingstatus=Ja
if errorlevel 1 set pingstatus=Nee
echo Computer: %1 >> %txt%
Echo Online: %pingstatus% >> %txt%
wmic /node:%1 /output:c:\tmp.txt product get name,version |findstr /c:"1E NomadBranch" c:\tmp.txt > %txt%

ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 100 >nul
echo 1eClient Geinstalleerd: %client% >> %txt%
echo 1eClient versie; >> %txt%
type tmp.txt >> %txt%
```

Update. This is the list I that WMIC create. I need to find the "1E NomadBranch" and import that to the %txt% file.

```
Compatibility Pack for the 2007 Office system                       12.0.6514.5001  
Microsoft Office Visio Viewer 2007                                  12.0.4518.1014  
Microsoft Software Update for Web Folders  (English) 14             14.0.6029.1000  
Microsoft Office OneNote MUI (English) 2010                         14.0.6029.1000  
Microsoft Office Standard 2010                                      14.0.6029.1000  
Microsoft Office Shared Setup Metadata MUI (English) 2010           14.0.6029.1000  
Microsoft Office Excel MUI (English) 2010                           14.0.6029.1000  
Microsoft Office PowerPoint MUI (English) 2010                      14.0.6029.1000  
Microsoft Office IME (Japanese) 2010                                14.0.4763.1000  
1E NomadBranch                                                      5.0.100         
Microsoft Office IME (Korean) 2010                                  14.0.4763.1000  
Microsoft Office IME (Chinese (Traditional)) 2010                   14.0.4763.1000  
Microsoft Office IME (Chinese (Simplified)) 2010                    14.0.4763.1000  
Microsoft Office Publisher MUI (English) 2010                       14.0.6029.1000  
Microsoft Office Outlook MUI (English) 2010                         14.0.6029.1000  
Microsoft Office ProofMUI (English) 2010                            14.0.4763.1000  
Microsoft Office Word MUI (English) 2010                            14.0.6029.1000  
Microsoft Office Proofing Kit 2010                                  14.0.4763.1000  
Microsoft Office Access Runtime 2010                                14.0.4763.1000  
Microsoft Office Access Runtime MUI (English) 2010                  14.0.4763.1000  
Microsoft Office Proofing (English) 2010                            14.0.6029.1000  
Microsoft Office Shared MUI (English) 2010                          14.0.6029.1000  
Microsoft Office Proof (Italian) 2010                               14.0.4763.1000  
Microsoft Office Proof (Catalan) 2010                               14.0.4763.1013  
Microsoft Office Proof (Dutch) 2010                                 14.0.4763.1000  
Microsoft Office Proof (German) 2010                                14.0.4763.1000  
Microsoft Office Proof (English) 2010                               14.0.6029.1000  
Adobe Flash Player 10 ActiveX                                       10.1.85.3       
Microsoft redistributable runtime DLLs VS2010 SP1 (x86)             10.0.40219.1    
Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 ATL Update kb973923 - x86 8.0.50727.4053  8.0.50727.4053  
Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 Service Pack 2                         3.2.30729       
OFFICE 2010 STANDARD P1                                             14.01.00.00     
Microsoft redistributable runtime DLLs VS2008 SP1(x86)              9.0             
WINZIP US V14.05.00.00.00                                           14.05.00.00     
Configuration Manager Client                                        5.00.7804.1000  
Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1                                    3.5.30729       
Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile                           4.0.30319       
Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Extended                                 4.0.30319
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you change

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%I in (list.txt) do call :pinger %%I goto :eof

:eof
move %txt% 1e-client
exit
```

to

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%I in (list.txt) do call :pinger %%I
move %txt% 1e-client
exit
```

because `:eof` is a special label meaning 'end of file`. It should not be assigned in a batchfile.

Also - it appears to have no purpose where it is. If you had coded

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%I in (list.txt) do call :pinger %%I&goto :eof
```

then the batch should have terminated after processing the first line in `list.txt`. As it stands, `goto` should merely have become an unused second parameter to `:pinger` and `:eof` an unused third parameter.

Personally, I only ever use `goto label` (no colon) except for `goto :eof` (the special condition) to avoid this very problem.

I believe the actual cause of your problem is here:

```
Echo Online: %pingstatus% >> %txt%
wmic /node:%1 /output:c:\tmp.txt product get name,version |findstr /c:"1E NomadBranch" c:\tmp.txt > %txt%

ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 100 >nul
```

This will echo whatever to the `txt` file, then run wmic and send its output to `c:\temp.txt` (since you specify `/output`) and send the screen output to findstr, which appears also to be reading `c:\temp.txt` which is probably open at the time... and to cap it all off, you are then redirecting the `findstr` output to a **new** `txt` (since you are using the `create new` redirector, `>`, not the `append` redirector, `>>`.

I'd suggest

```
Echo Online: %pingstatus% >> %txt%
wmic /node:%1 /output:c:\tmp.txt product get name,version 
findstr /c:"1E NomadBranch" c:\tmp.txt >> %txt%

ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 100 >nul
```

... but I'll admit having not tested that.

Comment: Thank your very much for the reply ! 
I tested the code. But the problem is. WMIC is working. But when i use FINDSTR I dont get any result to the %txt% file. I have a tmp txt with all the software. But how can make the 'filter' working and place that to the %txt%.

Comment: You would need to post a representative sample of the `temp.txt` file and describe what informationyou wish to extract.

Comment: I use this code:_findstr "1E NomadBranch" C:\tools\testomgeving\tmp%1.txt >> %txt% but it isn't working_. See my question for the list.

Comment: You appear to be creating `c:\tmp.txt` from `WMIC` and then searching `C:\tools\testomgeving\tmp%1.txt` for the text string, where the `%1` would be replaced by the contents of each line in `list.txt` in turn.

Comment: Its correct, I posted it here like c:\tmp.txt but its not working even when i use c:\tools\testomgeving\tmp%1.txt

Answer (score 1):

This line below has an error - did you correct it?

Instead of this

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%I in (list.txt) do call :pinger %%I goto :eof
```

use this (which assume no spaces etc in the terms)

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%I in (list.txt) do call :pinger %%I&goto :eof
```

This assumes you only want to process the first line of `list.txt`

Comment: When I add the & to %%I&GOTO the batch can't loop. When I use %%I GOTO it loops.

Comment: Then remove the `goto :eof` if you don't want to branch after the first line.